# How to calculate cursor delta like in FPS games?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making an XNA game and I'd like the cursor to stop when the mouse button is held down. Right now by setting the cursor position every 1/60 of a second to a certain location makes the cursor look laggy and sometimes if the cursor moves fast enough to reach a screen border, from that moment and until the next position reset the delta position is not calculated correctly. Also, starting at the edge of the screen and moving towards that same edge won't get any correct deltas.

How do I get the correct cursor deltas and not get bummed by cursor stopping at screen edges?

Comment: Are you trying to get the cursor to stop?  Or are you trying to get the cursor to decelerate and come to a stop when the mouse button is pressed?  Why are you trying to calculate the cursor deltas?

Comment: I guess I need to know how fast the cursor goes in what direction to know where to move the camera accordingly. Screen bounds are really great at preventing me from doing that.

Comment: Can't you just hide the cursor while the button is held and use the input to move the camera?

Comment: @MikeB if you could provide some details on how exactly to do that, avoiding bumping cursor into screen edges, it'd be great.

Answer (score 4):

If the position you are locking the mouse to is too close to the edge, you are out of luck.

I suggest you hide the cursor at the beginning of the drag motion, save the location and secretly move the cursor to the center of the screen. When dragging ends just restore the cursor to its previous location.

Comment: I suspect this is how it works, but I'd like to know if there are more and better solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Easily, supposing I understood what you meant.

In order to move a 1st person camera according to the mouse, we need to calculate the delta each frame, and then move the mouse back to the center of the screen.

To do so we will store the location of the center of the screen. We also need a MouseState variable and a yaw and a pitch floats to store our current camera rotations. I also like to set the rotation speed according the game's resolution:

```
MouseState currentMouseState;
Vector2 screenCenter;
float YrotationSpeed;
float XrotatiobSpeed;
float yaw = 0;
float pitch = 0;


...


protected override void LoadContent()
{
    YrotationSpeed = (float)graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 10000.0f;
    XrotatiobSpeed = (float)graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 12000.0f;

    screenCenter = new Vector2(graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height) / 2;
}
```

Now, to calculate how much did the mouse move in the last frame, we will use this function:

```
private void HandleMouse(GameTime gameTime)
{
    currentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
    float amount = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 1000.0f;
    if (currentMouseState.X != screenCenter.X)
    {
        yaw -= YrotationSpeed * (currentMouseState.X - screenCenter.X) * amount;
    }
    if (currentMouseState.Y != screenCenter.Y)
    {
        pitch -= XrotatiobSpeed * (currentMouseState.Y - screenCenter.Y) * amount;
        if (pitch > MathHelper.ToRadians(90))
            pitch = MathHelper.ToRadians(90);
        if (pitch < MathHelper.ToRadians(-50)) //Preventing the user from looking all the way down (and seeing the character doesn't have any legs..)
            pitch = MathHelper.ToRadians(-50);
    }
    Mouse.SetPosition((int)screenCenter.X, (int)screenCenter.Y);
}
```

Finally:

To update the camera and view Matrix, you could use the following function, that should be executed after we update our yaw and pitch:

```
public void UpdateCamera(float yaw, float pitch, Vector3 position)
{
    Matrix cameraRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(pitch) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(yaw);

    Vector3 cameraOriginalTarget = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
    Vector3 cameraRotatedTarget = Vector3.Transform(cameraOriginalTarget, cameraRotation);
    Vector3 cameraFinalTarget = position + cameraRotatedTarget;

    Vector3 cameraOriginalUpVector = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    Vector3 cameraRotatedUpVector = Vector3.Transform(cameraOriginalUpVector, cameraRotation);

    view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(position, cameraFinalTarget, cameraRotatedUpVector);
}
```

**EDIT:** Well, as I re-read the question I had realized my answer isn't quite what you were asking for. Nevertheless, it does show how to calculate the mouse delta without it getting to the borders of the screen.

To match my answer to your question, all you need are tiny adjustments.

By the way, unless you are willing to draw an image of a mouse in the middle of the screen, any methood WILL look kinda laggy. 
Therefore, I highly advice you to hide the cursor.
To do so, just add this line:

```
this.IsMouseVisible = false;
```